# Why are the fabry Perot Interference fringe sharper than Michelson interferometer fringe?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference, interferometry

Does it have anything to do with the fact that fabry Perot interferometer uses multiple beams while michelson only uses 2 beams

Comment: Yes, it's because the Fabry-Perot involves the interference of many reflected beams of light. In the same vein, the x-ray diffraction rings from the powder diffraction of a sample with very small crystallites will be broader than the diffraction rings from a sample with larger crystallites.

Comment: Why are multiple beam fringes sharper?

Comment: You can also observe the mutiple paths make sharper fringes in the comparison between a diffraction grating and a two-slit mask with the same spacing: fringes in the same places, but the grating makes a very sharp pattern.

Comment: Yes, but what's the rigorous reasoning behind it being sharper?

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer, because the last time I tried (for a student of mine) it stretched to more than four pages and still wasn't as clear on the page as in my head. I *think* it is best explained in the phasor framework, so if you are aware of that tool, you might want to mention it—it will give potential answer writers a jumping off point.